# Symfony KnpMenu no current class on menu item

Tags: symfony, knpmenubundle

I am learning about and starting to use the KnpMenu bundle. I read that " ... a current class is added to the "current" menu item by uri..", but I cannot figure out what this means exactly.
I tried a 2 item menu like this:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
```

and

```
**
 * Controller used to manage blog contents in the backend.
 *
 * @Route("/admin/post")
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
 *
 */
class BlogController extends Controller
{
      /**
     * Lists all Post entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="admin_index")
     * @Route("/", name="admin_post_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
```

with the following builder

```
public function mainMenu(FactoryInterface $factory, array $options)
    {
        $menu = $factory->createItem('root');

        $menu->addChild('Home', array('route' => 'homepage'));

        $menu->addChild('Blog', array('route' => 'admin_post_index'));

        return $menu;
    }
```

When I chose the home page, the li element has a **first** and a **current** class attribute – which is good –, but when I chose the Blog page, the li element has only the **last** class attribute but no **current** class attribute. 
I don't understand why?

Answer (score 0):

It could be caused by you having multiple routes with the same URL `/` in `BlogController`:

```
 * @Route("/", name="admin_index")
 * @Route("/", name="admin_post_index")
```

If you have the same URL, there is no need for multiple routes, just reuse the same route.